# How to upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to 13.10?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, updates, 13.10

My Ubuntu has a problem with the Ubuntu Software Center and I can't solve it, but I'd like to try the new version of Ubuntu, 13.10.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, can I upgrade to 13.10 how can I do that?
Its not dublicate :)